# Lightbox2 - Works fine until ~20th Image in gallery

Tags: javascript, css, gallery, lightbox, lightbox2

I currently have a photo gallery that has about 75 images in it. It works fine scrolling through using Lightbox2 until the 20th or so image in the series. Then the gallery goes blank and the display:none attribute doesn't go away.

Here is the HTML: https://codeshare.io/5wP7OR

here is the CSS: https://codeshare.io/adMKpZ

here is the JS: https://codeshare.io/5XWRPz

Does anyone have an idea why this would be happening? Thank you!

Comment: Here's a codepen link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YEBPLG

Comment: Your codepen demo is quite useless without having actual images. Anyway, maybe try alternatives, for example, fancybox.